# Jmeter - How to write inside user defined variables

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my test, I need to overwrite value under user defined variables.
Is it possible to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "overwrite"? Under user defined variables you only "declare" the variable along with initial value.

So if you:

1. Use the same variable name in the PostProcessor like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), if there will be a match - the variable will be "overwritten"
2. The variable can be overwritten using any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) by using [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) like:

   ```
    vars.put('X-API-USERID_1901', 'some other value')
   ```
3. There is [Set Variables Action](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/) plugin which provides GUI for setting user-defined variables in any arbitrary place of the test, it can also be used for "overwriting" the previously defined value

Comment: By overwrite I meant: change the value from 11 to ex: 12. Thanks for those hints. will try later